# Problems with implimention of the compareTo() method

Tags: java, comparable

Basically, I have 2 classes. One of them has a private member ArrayList(Objects from the other class) and every object from the list has a private field points. I have a method to iterate through the list and get the sum of all points. So I just want to compare list1 > list2 by their summed points. But I'm failing to achieve that - my compareTo() returns always 0.

Here is a short code example of this.

```
public class StudentsGroup implements IFile, Comparable {
    private List<Student> studentsList = new ArrayList<Student>();


    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        if(StudentsGroup.getTotalPoints(studentsList) < ((StudentsGroup)o).getTotalPoints(studentsList))
            return 1;
        else if(StudentsGroup.getTotalPoints(studentsList) > ((StudentsGroup)o).getTotalPoints(studentsList))
            return -1;
        else 
            return 0;
    }

    public static int getTotalPoints(List<Student> studentsList1) {
        int totalPoints = 0;
        for(Student o : studentsList1) {
            totalPoints += o.getStudentPoints();
        }
        return totalPoints;
    }
}
```

The method

Comment: have you dedugged to see what you are comparing? do you actually have entries in studentsList?

Comment: @Stultuske, yes I do. I initialize it in the constructor from a .txt file and and add objects of the student class in the list. I said that the actual method is working, when I print out the totalPoints, but the problem is that list1.compareTo(list2) always returns 0, as if the lists are always equal by points and they are not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 if(
  StudentsGroup.getTotalPoints(studentsList) <   
  ((StudentsGroup)o).getTotalPoints(studentsList))
```

You are passing the same `studentsList` to both sides of the calculation.

The "other group" `o` is not used at all.

It may look like `o` is used, but `getTotalPoints` is a `static` method and it does not matter what instance you call it on. The compiler will give you a warning about this, too. **Do not ignore compiler warnings.**

Immediate fix would be to change the code to

```
if( getTotalPoints(studentsList) < getTotalPoints((StudentsGroup)o).studentsList)
```

But you should probably change that `getTotalPoints` method from `public static` to `public` (not-static). Instead of the list being passed as a parameter, it can then just use `this.studentsList` internally.

```
if (this.getTotalPoints() < ((StudentsGroup)o).getTotalPoints())
```

Comment: Thank you. I must have the method as static, since the program is assignment, so I guess that my call to the static method was wrong. Btw, you need to put 1 more brace " ( " after the less symbol and one " ) " in the end to close the condition. :)

Answer (score 1):

In that case I would check the values are not both the same (or both 0)

```
public class StudentsGroup implements IFile, Comparable<StudentsGroup> {
    private List<Student> studentsList = new ArrayList<Student>();


    public int compareTo(StudentsGroup sg) {
        return Integer.compare(getTotalPoints(), sg.getTotalPoints());
    }

    public int getTotalPoints() {
        return Math.toIntExact(studentsList.stream()
                                           .mapToInt(Student::getStudentPoints).sum());
    }
}
```

By simplifying the code you are less likely to mix up a static method with an instance method `(StudentsGroup)o).getTotalPoints(studentsList)` just calls `StudentsGroup.getTotalPoints(studentsList)` as you don't have an instance method.

Comment: Also note that proper generic types on `Comparable<>` remove the need for the typecasts.

Comment: and this code does not calculate each sum twice (which the original code might have to do). That can also be achieved by local variables.

Comment: @Thilo I have added using Math.toIntExact rather than `(int)` ;)

Comment: Neat. I just meant that there are no `(StudentsGroup)o` casts necessary in your code (because of proper types on `Comparable`).